# Error with migrate of django-firebird

Tags: python, django, firebird, firebird2.5

Running the migrate command with **django-firebird** will result in the following error:

It's a problem associated with automatically generated user tables, so it's hard to fix it.

I would appreciate any help on how to resolve it.

```
  Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, mdlservice, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emptyspear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\emptyspear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\firebird\base.py", line 236, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(q, params)
  File "C:\Users\emptyspear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 3627, in execute
    self._ps._execute(parameters)
  File "C:\Users\emptyspear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 3333, in _execute
    "Error while executing SQL statement:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while executing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -607\n- unsuccessful metadata update\n- MODIFY RDB$RELATION_FIELDS failed\n- action cancelled by trigger (1) to preserve data integrity\n- Cannot update index segment used by an Integrity Constraint', -607, 335544351)
```

The development environment is as follows

os : windows10

python : 3.5.4

django : 1.10.8

fdb : 2.0.0

firebird : 2.5(32bit)

django-firebird : https://github.com/maxirobaina/django-firebird

Comment: "MODIFY RDB$RELATION_FIELDS failed" - this means Django uses dirty hacks that it should replace with `ALTER TABLE` on newer Firebird versions. I admit that is a moving target as FB evolves 2.1 to 2.5 to 3.0, so can be complex thing. // "Cannot update index segment used by an Integrity Constraint'" = and that is perhaps another case of FB hardening. Or Django fails at dependencies analysis. I suggest you open bug report on github page and invite developers here for more information if they would need it

Comment: @Arioch'The That is not necessarily true, I haven't verified it yet, but I think you can get this error if you alter a field that is used in a foreign key constraint. Behind the scenes of `alter table` statements, Firebird itself modifies system tables, and that can produce this error as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel then Django wrongfully reports what it is doing. The "MODIFY RDB$RELATION_FIELDS failed" is not a message FB 2.5 itself can generate, can it ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes it is. `MODIFY` is the equivalent of `UPDATE` in the alternative (embedded) GDL query language that it is used internally a lot in the implementation. This was the original query language before SQL surfaced as the standard query language. See for example https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/src/dsql/DdlNodes.epp#L647

Comment: Error suggests that the upgrade makes a modification that is disallowed because of dependencies between tables. I suggest you create an issue on https://github.com/maxirobaina/django-firebird. The alternative is probably to create a new empty table and copy the data from the old to the new database.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice and answers.

As Mark advised, I posted the above question on the Django-Firebird GitHub issues